# Julia npzread(filename.npz) very slow

Tags: python-3.x, julia

I want to load numpy arrays inside julia, but it is very slow to load *.npz files.

python3 code

```
import numpy as np
x = np.zeros([300, 400])
y = np.zeros([500, 600])

np.save('somepath/x.npy', x)
np.save('somepath/y.npy', y)
np.savez('somepath/xy.npz', x=x, y=y)
```

julia 0.6 code

```
using NPZ

function load_xy()
    xy = npzread("somepath/xy.npz")
end

function load_x_and_y()
    x = npzread("somepath/x.npy")
    y = npzread("somepath/y.npy")
end

@time(load_xy())
@time(load_x_and_y())
```

> load_xy():
>   **22.071646 seconds** (24.99 M allocations: 820.903 MiB, 0.87% gc time)
>   load_x_and_y():
>   **0.010131 seconds** (2.88 k allocations: 9.782 MiB, 19.20% gc time)

QUESTIONS:

Why the large number of allocations for load_xy()?

How can I change my code so that load_xy() also is fast?

Comment: What are the times when you doing it twice? I suspect some setup/compilation-time is included measuring the first `load_xy()`

Comment: load_x_and_y():


`0.668960 seconds (504.59 k allocations: 36.981 MiB, 6.03% gc time)`
`0.043598 seconds (409 allocations: 9.633 MiB, 95.01% gc time)`

load_xy():


`21.579099 seconds (24.49 M allocations: 793.708 MiB, 0.56% gc time)`
`21.420268 seconds (24.48 M allocations: 793.317 MiB, 0.19% gc time)`

Comment: I looked at the source for [npz.jl](https://github.com/fhs/NPZ.jl/blob/master/src/NPZ.jl) on GitHub and I found that the line of code taking all of the processing time is line 197:
`x = map(toh, read(f, typ, reverse(hdr.shape)...))`
After investigating further, I think the problem is a bug in the `Base.read` function that gets called.  I concluded that sorting out whatever is wrong there is a bit over my head. You could re-implement your own read logic using npz.jl as an example, but I think that is more than anyone wants to do. Just load the *.npy files.